# Jmeter Recording xml issue

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to record a script  for web application (https protocol)using jmeter-5.3. The xml file in the view result tree of HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder is capturing all the calls. but once I finished my recording and check the xml file doesn't have the calls(the first 3-4 transaction calls) in the beginning of the script in the xml. why its happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

1. According to JMeter Best Practices you should be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.4.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/dbg1bxywcwx5vtdwqf8ownf7ppgqjn41) (or whatever is the latest version which is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)
2. Check "Grouping" setting of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), it might be the case you have `Store 1st sampler of each group only` selected and it can discard important requests:

   [image]
3. Make sure to use [Recording Template](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#basic-instructions) as it generates good and valid recording test plan
4. Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries
5. Try alternative way of recording a JMeter test i.e. [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium) and see whether all requests which should be captured are captured.